# NullInjectorError: No provider for Storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

Im Builing an application where i can take photos and save them to the ionic storage, but when i save them i start my application i get following error

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(RecentPageModule)[PhotoService -> PhotoService -> PhotoService -> Storage -> Storage]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Storage!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(RecentPageModule)[PhotoService -> PhotoService -> PhotoService -> Storage -> Storage]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Storage!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:8650:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9076:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9076:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:627:33)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:631:60)
    at Object.PhotoService_Factory [as factory] (photo.service.ts:21:26)
```

if figured it out that the error appears when i call a Storage element in the constructor, but i need a Storage object to call the set() method later in  my code.

Any suggestions?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Plugins, Capacitor  } from '@capacitor/core';
import { Camera,CameraResultType, CameraPhoto } from '@capacitor/camera';
import { FilesystemDirectory,Filesystem } from '@capacitor/filesystem';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

//const {Camera,Filesystem,Storage} = Plugins;


//const {Storage} = '@ionic/storage'

export interface Photo{
  filepath:string;
  webViewPath: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PhotoService {


  public photo: Photo[]=[];
  private PHOTO_STORAGE: string = "photos";

  constructor(private platform: Platform,public store: Storage) { }

  public async captureImage(){


    const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality:100,
      allowEditing: true,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Uri
    });
    console.log(image)


    const imageFile = await this.savePicture(image);
    this.photo.unshift(imageFile as any);

    console.log(this.photo)

    this.store.set(this.PHOTO_STORAGE, JSON.stringify(this.photo))
  }

  private async savePicture(cameraPhto:CameraPhoto){
    const base64Data = await this.readAsBase64(cameraPhto);
    const fileName = new Date().getTime() + '.jpeg';

    const savedFile = await Filesystem.writeFile({
      path: fileName,
      data:base64Data as string,
      directory: FilesystemDirectory.Data
    });
    console.log('saved', savedFile)

    if(this.platform.is('hybrid')){
      return{
        filepath: savedFile.uri,
        webviewPath: Capacitor.convertFileSrc(savedFile.uri)
      }
    }else{
      return{
        filePath: fileName,
        webviewPath: cameraPhto.webPath
      }

    }
  }

  private async readAsBase64(cameraPhto:CameraPhoto){
    if(this.platform.is('hybrid')){
      const file = await Filesystem.readFile({
        path:cameraPhto.path as string
      });
      return file.data;

    }else{
      //we are on the web
      const response = await fetch(cameraPhto.webPath as string);
      const blob = await response.blob()
      return await this.convertBlobToBase64(blob);
    }

  }

  convertBlobToBase64= (blob: Blob) => new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    const reader = new FileReader;
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.onload = () =>{
      resolve(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
  });

}
```

Comment: and did you provide a `Storage` ???

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic, you should import the `IonicStorageModule` in order to use the service `Storage`

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And you should import `Storage` from `import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';` according to the official doc https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage